# Android; Messages are available on Datainputstream, but cant read

Tags: android, client, blocking, outputstream

My client sends a UTF message to the server and it catches it correctly without any problems. But when the server replies my Dataoutputstream.available() shows more than 1 for every data I receieve, additively. The problem is readUTF() doesnt work trying to get those messages from the stream...Is there any blocking thing or so that prevents reading data?

Comment: Very likely it is blocked. Read [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#available())

Comment: So like.....what can I do to unblock or read?

Comment: As I am not exactly sure what is your requirement, i suggest you use **InputStreamReader** with ***ready()*** function to check whether you can start reading without blocking.

Comment: What do you mean "no use"?